# How to convert tensorflow model file to tensorflow lite? graph.pb to graph.lite

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite

(base) C:\tensorflow-master>bazel run --config=opt \ //tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco:toco -- \ --input_file=optimized_graph.pb \ --output_file=abc.tflite \ --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \ --output_format=TFLITE \ --inference_type=FLOAT \ --input_shape=1,128,128,3 \ --input_array=input \ --output_array=final_result
WARNING: Config values are not defined in any .rc file: opt
ERROR: No targets found to run
INFO: Elapsed time: 11.002s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
ERROR: Build failed. Not running target

Comment: This is answered here, check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58583419/11517841

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that you failed to build TOCO.

The C++ toco converter has been deprecated, in favor of the python API.
See these [docs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/g3doc/python_api.md#api).