# Convert InceptionV3 pb file to tflite

Tags: tensorflow, toco

I'm trying to convert InceptionV3 model from pb file to tflite file with TOCO. I use the following command:

```
tflite_convert --output_file=/home/luca/Scrivania/prova.tflite --graph_def_file=/home/luca/Scrivania/inception_v3_2016_08_28_frozen.pb/inception_v3_2016_08_28_frozen.pb --input_arrays=input --output_arrays="InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1:0"
```

But i get the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid tensors 'InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1:0' were found.
```

How i can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error indicates that the `output_array` you provided is incorrect. In general, the output array for InceptionV3 models is `InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape`.

If this doesn't work, the next step is to visualize your TensorFlow `.pb` model in TensorBoard and look for the output array.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to know the "--output_arrays=" . make a python file inside where frozen_inference_graph.pb folder is located and then paste this code in the py

```
import tensorflow as tf
gf = tf.GraphDef()
m_file = open('tflite_graph.pb','rb')
gf.ParseFromString(m_file.read())

with open('somefile.txt', 'a') as the_file:
    for n in gf.node:
        the_file.write(n.name+'\n')

file = open('somefile.txt','r')
data = file.readlines()
print ("output name = ")
print (data[len(data)-1])

print ("Input name = ")
file.seek ( 0 )
print (file.readline())
```

Once you have run the file it will show the input_arrays and output_arrays.

furthe info check at : [How to convert .pb to TFLite format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52918051/how-to-convert-pb-to-tflite-format)