# Where can I find Tensorflow lite projects for object landmarks detection ( for e.g face landmarks )?

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, tensorflow-lite

I have worked on eye detection project with landmarks on Android and I have tried to integrate the model using Tensorflow lite and MLKit custom model (firebase).
Unfortunately, I have failed to get good results ( predictions of eye landmarks ).

For that reason, I would like to know where can I find examples of a project that worked with the same context ( object detection with landmarks).

I search in the Github, but I didn't find any project related to my work.

Comment: You can train your model using tensorflow/tf.keras and convert .pb model to .tflite using tflite_convert tool. Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52918051) or [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/cmdline_examples). For facial landmark detection you can check out this [repo](https://github.com/yinguobing/cnn-facial-landmark)

Comment: check this out : https://www.journaldev.com/15629/android-face-detection

Comment: @bit01 I have trained and I have the tensorflow lite model, the problem is on the integrating ( pre-processing )

Comment: @yuvrajsinh Thanks, but I'm not searching for project that works with SDK ( like google vision or MLKit face detection ), I search for projects that used tensorflow lite model ( custom model )

Comment: You may want to check out: [tensorflow lite example](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples) or [android tensorflow lite example](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-TensorFlow-Lite-Example)

Comment: @bit01 I see those examples, the problem of my CNN is that it gives output arrays not classification with labels, I mean that I don't have a labels.txt and those examples are just for classification not for drawing object landmarks ( face landmarks )