# I cant convert .pb file to .tflite

Tags: python, tensorflow, model, tensorboard

I need .tflite file to use the model that i trained in android.

I will use this code but i don’t know the input array and the output array values:

```
  tflite_convert \ 
--output_file=object_detection\outputtflite  \ 
--graph_def_file=object_detection\out\frozen_inference_graph.pb\ 
--input_arrays=input\ 
--output_arrays=output
```

I heard that i can learn input_arrays and
output_arrays values from tensorboard but they don’t appear in there. I use this code:

```
tensorboard --logdir=object_detection\out\
```

There are these errors in my tensorboard screen:

[image: GRAPHS]
[image: İMAGES]

My out folder looks like this:

[image: outFolder]

What can i do about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the summarize_graph to inspect the graph.
This can help you solve the problem
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms#inspecting-graphs

Answer (score 0):

to check for input_arrays and output_arrays. make a python file inside where frozen_inference_graph.pb folder is located and then paste this code in the py

```
import tensorflow as tf
gf = tf.GraphDef()
m_file = open('tflite_graph.pb','rb')
gf.ParseFromString(m_file.read())

with open('somefile.txt', 'a') as the_file:
    for n in gf.node:
        the_file.write(n.name+'\n')

file = open('somefile.txt','r')
data = file.readlines()
print ("output name = ")
print (data[len(data)-1])

print ("Input name = ")
file.seek ( 0 )
print (file.readline())
```

Once you have run the file it will show the input_arrays and output_arrays.

furthe info check at : [How to convert .pb to TFLite format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52918051/how-to-convert-pb-to-tflite-format)