# AttributeError: type object 'TFLiteConverterV2' has no attribute 'from_keras_model_file'

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I am having one TensorFlow Keras module "model.h5". I want to generate tflite from it. I am using the below-mentioned code for that. I am using tensorflow version '2.0.0'.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import lite

dataset_dir = "C:\\Users\\Ravi\\dataset"
IMAGE_SIZE = 224
saved_keras_model = "C:\\Users\\Ravi\\model.h5"

def representative_data_gen():
  dataset_list = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(dataset_dir + '/*/*')
  for i in range(100):
    image = next(iter(dataset_list))
    image = tf.io.read_file(image)
    image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE])
    image = tf.cast(image / 255., tf.float32)
    image = tf.expand_dims(image, 0)
    yield [image]

converter =  lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(saved_keras_model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
# This ensures that if any ops can't be quantized, the converter throws an error
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
# These set the input and output tensors to uint8
converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8
# And this sets the representative dataset so we can quantize the activations
converter.representative_dataset = representative_data_gen
tflite_model = converter.convert()

with open('mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_quant.tflite', 'wb') as f:
      f.write(tflite_model)
```

I am getting this kind of error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Ravi\face-mask-models\tflite_model.py", line 28, in <module>
    converter =  lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(saved_keras_model)

AttributeError: type object 'TFLiteConverterV2' has no attribute 'from_keras_model_file'
```

What can be the problem? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

From [this page](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization) you get this info:

Integer only
Creating integer only models is a common use case for TensorFlow Lite for Microcontrollers and Coral Edge TPUs.

Additionally, to ensure compatibility with integer only devices (such as 8-bit microcontrollers) and accelerators (such as the Coral Edge TPU), you can enforce full integer quantization for all ops including the input and output, by using the following steps:

```
import tensorflow as tf
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model('model.h5')
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
def representative_dataset_gen():
  for _ in range(num_calibration_steps):
    # Get sample input data as a numpy array in a method of your choosing.
    yield [input]
converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset_gen
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.int8  # or tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8  # or tf.uint8
tflite_quant_model = converter.convert()
```

So I assume that you want to ensure compatibility with integer only devices with the above code.

If you do not need that and you only want to convert your model do:

```
# WHOLE MODEL
tflite_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(tflite_model)
tflite_save = converter.convert()
open("generated.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_save)
```

Generally speaking at your code is missing a 'tf' in front of 'lite'so at the specific line should be:

```
converter =  tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(saved_keras_model)
```

instead of:

```
converter =  lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(saved_keras_model)
```

and you could always upgrade to TF v 2.2.0 if something is not working.

Tag me if you need anything else

Comment: in  for _ in range(num_calibration_steps), what is num_calibration_steps? if possible then can you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: Hi mevada.. Do you want to quantize the model or not?

Comment: @Farmaker I'm unclear on what `num_calibration_steps` is too. Would you mind explaining? I'm extremely new to ML so sorry if it is supposed to be obvious. It doesnt seem to be explained at the link you gave.

Comment: I copied code from official link of Tensorflow. It does not provide more details on what you ask. If you want me to take a look also and try convert your file send model.h5 to my email address farmaker47@gmail.com

Comment: Check this answer also https://stackoverflow.com/a/62675805/7118084